# How to target a title attribute in a link with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to hide the title of a link popping out in firefox but I am getting an error if I do the following:

```
$('a["title"]').on('mouseenter', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Console

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a["title"]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Omit the double quotes in the attribute selector. It should be `a[title]`:

```
$('a[title]').on('mouseenter', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

The quotes usually represent an attribute's value. For instance, `a[title="value"]`.

For further reference, the correct syntax for an attribute selector [can be found here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors).